# nextjs server side rendering styling lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js

I not sure what is happening with my react nextjs app. On startup, if I were to navigate to the sign in page, the styles do not render with the component. However, if I went directly to the sign in endpoint, the styles render. Here is what it looks like with styling:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when i initially navigate to signin endpoint from another endpoint:

[image]

Do this actually have anything to do with server side rendering? I'm not directly looking for a full solution from the community but rather a general understanding of what is happening with nextjs rendering

Comment: please show the code where you add styles

Comment: Do you use production build or development build? and Which CSS you are using? mean to say LESS, SCSS or anything else